# How to validate and show errors in a PHP input without pressing SUBMIT button?

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have a user registration form in php and mysql as follows.
I need to validate each input field before the user moves to the next field AND without submitting a button. The user must submit the form once all the fields are filled properly or it should prompt the error at the filling field?
How can i do that.

For an example:- i need to validate the NIC Number once it is filled and should show if there is any error in the formatting once moved to the Name field and before submitting the form.

```
<form action='register.php' method='post'>
NIC Number : <select class='drdwn1' name='idtype'>
<option value="old">Old</option>
<option value="new">New</option>  
</select>
<input type='text' name='nic'/>

Name with Initials : <select class='drdwn1' name='saluation'>
<option value="Mr.">Mr.</option> 
<option value="Ms.">Ms.</option> 
</select>

<input type='text' name='name' />
Address : <input type='text' name='address' />
Occupation : <input type='text' name='occupation' />
Contact Number : <input type='text' name='contactno'/>
Email Address : <input type='text' name='email' placeholder=''/>
Password : <input type='password' name='password' ></br>
Confirm Password : <input type='password' name='password1' />
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' >
</form>




<?

php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

$Idtype=$_POST['idtype'];
$Nic=$_POST['nic'];
$Saluation=$_POST['saluation'];
$Name=$_POST['name'];
$Address=$_POST['address'];
$Occupation=$_POST['occupation'];
$Contactno=$_POST['contactno'];
$Email=$_POST['email'];
$Username=$_POST['nic'];
$Password=$_POST['password'];
$Password1=$_POST['password1'];
$email = filter_var($Email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

$check=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from user.admin WHERE username='$Username'");
$checkrows=mysqli_num_rows($check);

    // Check if User exist
    if($checkrows>0) {
    echo "<p class='msgp1'>Your username already exist!</p>";
    }
    // Check if User exist

    // Check Manditory fields
    else if(empty($_POST['nic'] AND $_POST['email'] AND $_POST['password'])){
    echo "<p class='msgp1'>Please fill the mandetory fields!</p>";
    }
    // Check Manditory fields

    // Validate Email
    else if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo("<p class='msgp1'>$email is not a valid email address!</p>");
    }
    // Validate Email

    //if old ID and and not filled V
    else if (strlen($Nic) == '10' AND !preg_match("/^[0-9]+[0-9]+[0-9]+[0-9]+[0-9]+[0-9]+[0-9]+[0-9]+[0-9]+[V,X]$/i", $Nic)){
    echo "<p class='msgp1'>Should have the letter V or X at the end!</p>";
    }
    //Validate ID Number

    // Validate Password
    else if(($_POST['password'] !== $_POST['password1'])){
    echo "<p class='msgp1'>Password must mach!</p>";
    }
    // Validate Password


else{

$sql = "INSERT INTO user.admin (nic, saluation, name, address, city, bday, occupation, contactno, email, username, password) VALUES ('$Nic','$Saluation','$Name','$Address','$Occupation','$Contactno','$Email','$Username','$Password')";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {

Echo "Success!";
}
}
}

?>
```

Comment: You could either use (client-side) jQuery validate the form inputs, or possible AJAX to post to a (server-side) PHP script.

Comment: Set `onblur` event for your inputs that will validate the value

Comment: What research have you done? This problem should already be solved at least 1000 times and there are many tutorials about it.

Comment: There are three things you can do. Two of them are client-side, which is what you are looking for: a browser's built-in validation capabilities and custom JavaScript. Server-side there is PHP, which you should do additionally, as users can easily work around your client-side checks if they so desire. You should read through [this MDN article on form validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation), it explains _everything_.

Comment: Also, Priyantha, could you please take the time to properly format your code? That's common courtesy. Cheers!

Comment: FYI, you can simplify your regular expression to `/^\d{9}[V,X]$/`

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript! Is powerful and works fine with this problems.
Suppose you have a function
function validateNIC(param){...}

You could use this as follows:

```
<input type='text' name='nic' onblur="validateNIC(this.value)"/>
```

where I used "onblur" event, but you can customize it on your needs.

Naturally, this is only a syntactic control. If you wanted to perform actions such as database queries or in general a server-side control, this is not the thing to do: you should use, for example, Ajax technology, for an asynchronous communication with the server without submit the form data.

Comment: Also, everyone with basic HTML/JavaScript knowledge will be able to easily remove all of the validation and send invalid data to OP's server.

Comment: It depends on the kind of validation. If you want a syntactic control, this is ok, but for advanced control a server-side control is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with Javascript with a keyup event.

```
$('input').keyup(function() {
//code...
});
```

you could put all of the requirements you want to set said input in there.

Answer (score 0):

First, form validation is a topic covered in many tutorials and documentations on the Internet and there is no point in me just reinventing the wheel. Interestingly enough, I could not find an exact duplicate question on Stack Overflow, so I'll give you a rough outline, based (or backed up) by [this fantastic article on form validation from the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation) - go read it, it will teach you everything.

**Now, there are [three possible ways of validating a form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation#Different_types_of_form_validation):**

- Browser's built-in validation (*client-side*)
- Custom JavaScript (*client-side*)
- PHP (or another *server-side* language)

**It is important to understand that all client-side validations can easily be disabled or circumvented by the user**, which means that you absolutely have to do server-side validation. Client-side validation is only additional convenience.

If you want to perform client-side validation, the easiest way would be to make use of modern browser's built-in functionality. This can be achieved through attributes like [`required`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-required), [`maxlength`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-maxlength) or even [`pattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-pattern), which can be given to form input elements.

JavaScript (or jQuery) solutions can be used in addition if the built-in solutions do not suffice for your specific use case. There are [plenty](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) [of](http://www.formvalidator.net/) [options](http://formvalidation.io/) out there.

Answer (score -1):

use `onfocusout` for client side validation [example](https://www.w3schools.com/jsreF/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onfocusout)

Comment: This is not going to help OP much, seeing how they are pretty much at a loss regarding form validation in general.

Answer (score -1):

We can use available client side validation plug ins like:

https://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/

Similarly we can use php server side validation like:

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_validation.asp

Comment: So what are the differences? When should we use one over the other, or even both? Are there native JavaScript solutions? Or even some that don't use any JavaScript? Seeing how OP seems to be a beginner, this answer could really need some more details.

Comment: We can use both. In case client has disabled javascript from browser, it will not validate anything. So it's better to use both validations.

Comment: I know that. But OP probably doesn't. It should be part of your answer.

Comment: Then why raised question. Go and take some sleep. don't mark false answers.

Comment: I was simply trying to help you to improve your answer.